# Does std::vector automatically do deep copies of pointers to arrays from one vector object to another?

Tags: c++

If I have two `std::vector` objects and I attempt to copy one to another using the assignment operator:

```
v2 = v1;
```

Will it create a deep copy of the array pointed to by `v1` automatically?  Or do I have to overload the assignment operator whenever I want to do this, if I am using `std::vector` in another class that I am writing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are making a deep copy any time you copy a vector. But, if you have a vector of pointers, you are only getting a copy of the pointers, not the values they are pointing at.

For example:

```
std::vector<Foo> f;
std::vector<Foo> cp = f; //deep copy. All Foo copied

std::vector<Foo*> f;
std::vector<Foo*> cp = f; //deep copy (of pointers), or shallow copy (of objects).
//All pointers to Foo are copied, but not Foo themselves
```

Comment: Okay.  The textbook that I am reading has a custom vector class written that seems to be illustrative of vector, but I am just making sure.  According to the textbook, the default copy constructor included in classes automatically would not be substantial enough for vector to be able to make a deep copy, only a shallow copy.  I am assuming that it has a modified copy constructor declared.  I am having trouble understanding the documentation regarding this.  Am I correct?

Comment: @MichaelFox It depends what you mean.  `std::vector`'s copy constructor and assignment operator make a deep copy of the `std::vector` object, but it's up to the copy constructor and/or assignment operator of the objects contained in the vector as to how they're copied.  `std::vector` has no control over what the contained objects' copy constructor does.  It's up to the class author to provide copy semantics that make sense for that class.

Comment: @Miles Budnek "std::vector's copy constructor and assignment operator make a deep copy of the std::vector object" This answered it.  I was only wondering about std::vector itself.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

C++ vector is auto deep copy. But the vector element is not. So you need to overload operator= of the element if it's a complex structure include pointer.